# when I repeat data retrived from mysql using php, Javascript work only on the first record?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I have a little problem that drove me crazy
the thing is , I'm retrieving records from mysql database
and displaying these records , under each record there's should be a countdown javascript clock which takes the value from mysql
It works only with the first record and the other records are only text , Here's the HTML , PHP and JS:

```
<a>
    <div>
    <? echo $row['Device Name']; ?>
    </div>
    <? $Remain = $row['Remaining Time']; ?>
    <font color="red" size="6"><span id="countdown"> <? echo $Remain; ?></span></font>
    <img src="img/stop.png" /> 
    </a>  



<script type="text/javascript">

    // Initialize clock countdowns by using the total seconds in the elements tag

   secs       =  parseInt(document.getElementById('countdowno').innerHTML,10);
   setTimeout("countdown('countdowno',"+secs+")", 1000);




    /**
     * Countdown function
     * Clock count downs to 0:00 then hides the element holding the clock
     * @param id Element ID of clock placeholder
     * @param timer Total seconds to display clock
     */
    function countdown(id, timer){
        timer--;
        minRemain  = Math.floor(timer / 60);
        secsRemain = new String(timer - (minRemain * 60));
        // Pad the string with leading 0 if less than 2 chars long
        if (secsRemain.length < 2) {
            secsRemain = '0' + secsRemain;
        }

        // String format the remaining time
        clock      = minRemain + ":" + secsRemain;
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = clock;
        if ( timer > 0 ) {
            // Time still remains, call this function again in 1 sec
            setTimeout("countdown('" + id + "'," + timer + ")", 1000);
        } else {
            // Time is out! Hide the countdown
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        }

    }
</script>
```

Please Help me to be able to make the js counter work for each record 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use the id `countdown` for multiple spans, but everyone has to have another unique id, so you can point to each one.

```
<?php $id = uniqid(); /* create unique id for each row */ ?>
<a>
    <div>
    <? echo $row['Device Name']; ?>
    </div>
    <? $Remain = $row['Remaining Time']; ?>
    <font color="red" size="6"><span id="countdown_<?php echo $id; ?>"> <? echo $Remain; ?></span></font>
    <img src="img/stop.png" /> 
    </a>  



<script type="text/javascript">

    // Initialize clock countdowns by using the total seconds in the elements tag

   secs       =  parseInt(document.getElementById('countdown_<?php echo $id; ?>').innerHTML,10);
   setTimeout("countdown('countdown_<?php echo $id; ?>',"+secs+")", 1000);




    /**
     * Countdown function
     * Clock count downs to 0:00 then hides the element holding the clock
     * @param id Element ID of clock placeholder
     * @param timer Total seconds to display clock
     */
    function countdown(id, timer){
        timer--;
        minRemain  = Math.floor(timer / 60);
        secsRemain = new String(timer - (minRemain * 60));
        // Pad the string with leading 0 if less than 2 chars long
        if (secsRemain.length < 2) {
            secsRemain = '0' + secsRemain;
        }

        // String format the remaining time
        clock      = minRemain + ":" + secsRemain;
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = clock;
        if ( timer > 0 ) {
            // Time still remains, call this function again in 1 sec
            setTimeout("countdown('" + id + "'," + timer + ")", 1000);
        } else {
            // Time is out! Hide the countdown
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        }

    }
</script>
```

Additionally it would be better, if you define `countdown()` once outside the loop and not in every row new

Comment: Although it didn't work directly but you inspired me what I did was I added the java script after the php code and to be repeated in the my sql while loop   `<? $Remain = $row['Remaining Time']; ?>
 <font color="red" size="6">   <span id='countdownn_<? echo $id; ?>'><? echo $Remain;?></span></font></br>
 <script type="text/javascript">   
   secs       =  parseInt(document.getElementById('countdownn_<? echo $id; ?>').innerHTML,10);
   setTimeout("countdown('countdownn_<? echo $id; ?>',"+secs+")", 1000);
 
 </script>` so thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

The id for HTML element is expected to be unique, you can use class instead if you want to select all wanted element by one name.

```
<span id="countdown">
```

You can add class:

```
<span class="countdown">
```